# Can't find coda plist

Tags: plist, coda

I can't seem to find my Coda plist. I've searched all throughout my library (including the `Preferences` folder), and I can't seem to find it. I've searched my computer, and that doesn't work either... Can anyone else find their coda plist?

Comment: Have you recently upgraded to Mac OS X 10.7 Lion? Every user's ~/Library/ folder is *hidden* in Lion by default, so if you are searching for many things, you won't find them!

Comment: IT isn't hidden, its just hard to get to. (You have to go to Disk Utility and Reveal the Hard Drive in finder and then go from there)

Comment: Technically, it is hidden by the Mac OS X filesystem. That is the correct term. The path to the folder is prefaced by "." as in "/.Library". To reveal it, you can use a command-line command to change its designation to remove the ".", thus making it visible.

Comment: Perhaps on your computer, but on mine I did not have to reveal my hidden files...

Comment: What do you mean "reveal the hard drive" in DU? We are talking about a directory, not a partition (or an HD). The `~/Library` directory is *indeed* hidden under Lion but it is not prefaced by a "." like @WheatWilliams has said. It is actually only hidden to Finder using the `chflags` command (`chflags nohidden ~/Library` will unhide it). Or you can hold the ALT key when you're in the Go menu in Finder, it will show up in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Coda's preference plist file is stored here:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.panic.Coda.plist
```

There's also `~/Library/Preferences/com.panic.Coda.LSSharedFileList.plist`. I'm not sure what this does exactly, but it doesn't appear to store preferences.

Comment: I looked there and couldn't find it, maybe I accidentally deleted it...

Comment: @Odinulf If it has been deleted, opening Coda will put in a new one with the default values.

Comment: That *should* be the case, but it does not refresh the plist in my case.

Comment: @Odinulf are you aware that there are *two* libraries? One is in the root, the other in your user's home directory. Be sure to check them both.

Comment: Of course I checked both.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in my system using [FileZilla](http://www.filezilla.de/) :-) which shows hidden files.